# How to view the implementation of CoroutineCrudRepository automatically generated by Spring R2DBC?

Tags: spring, r2dbc

I can't find the logic for generating the implementation of CoroutineCrudRepository.
It seems like it's not found within the Spring R2DBC module. Could you please tell me where it is or how it's created?